# TimedRotatingFileHandler not logging from helper modules

Tags: python, logging

Using Python 3.3, I am trying to log from helper libs as well as a main script.  File structure:

```
Lib\
    __init__.py
    helper1.py
    helper2.py

script.py
```

At the top of each helper module, I have

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

If I use `basicConfig` in `script.py`, all logging from the modules comes through fine.  However, if I try to use a `TimedRotatingFileHandler`, I only get logging from `script.py`

**basicConfig** - works as expected:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

logging.basicConfig(filename='log_file.log',
                format='%(levelname)s - %(asctime)s - %(message)s',
                level=logging.DEBUG)


logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

**TimedRotatingFileHandler -** logging from helper libs does not come through:

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import TimedRotatingFileHandler

handler = TimedRotatingFileHandler('rotating_log_file.log',
                                when = "d",
                                interval = 1,
                                backupCount =5)

formatter = logging.Formatter("%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s")
handler.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(handler)

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

How do I get it so all logging comes through using a `TimedRotatingFileHander`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the handler to and set the level on the root logger - i.e. in script.py only,

```
root_logger = logging.getLogger()
root_logger.addHandler(handler)
root_logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

And then just use the other `logger` variables for actually logging.

Comment: `set the level on the root logger` it is perfect to me